# Read values from custom USB device

Tags: c, macos, iokit

I have a USB device (bicycle computer) and want to read from it values (odometer value, average speed, etc.) through the USB port. After some steps I managed to detect the computer and read some parameters (like `vendorId`, `sessionId`, `deviceName` etc.), but I don't know how I can read bicycle values.

There is no documentation for this device. I am looking for a solution on an IOKit framework.

Comment: What is this device? If you don't have any documentation for it, how do you expect others to know what you're talking about?

Comment: This device is bicycle computer with usb-station. I am interesting in general approaches and don't expect, what you could provide me with code snippets.

Comment: For starters, you could provide some more details about what you did and how you've accomplished it.

Comment: Computer is http://www.sigmasport.de/us/produkte/bikecomputer/topline_2009_wired/bc1609/?punkt=features
and I write a program, that lists all usb devices like in apple sample USBPrivateDataSample https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/USBPrivateDataSample/Introduction/Intro.html

As I think, computer should have memory storage, and I should read memory from storage and convert it to desired values, but I am really not sure in this approach

Comment: You cannot be sure that the device supports extracting this data, you will need API documentation to verify that. Without it, it would be very painful to reverse-engineer the device in order to extract the required values, if this is possible at all.

Comment: Thanks. I bought program from official site, and this program can read these values as well. Sad what I can't do it )

Comment: With an existing driver, you can reverse engineer it by watching the data it sends and receives via the USB bus when you perform different operations. Based on that you can then write your own driver. This is usually a lot of work, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install usbview. This is a nice and it lets you read all the descriptors
http://www.kroah.com/linux/usb/

Another thread ( [USB programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241207/usb-programming)) also give link of 
http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/

There are sample provided which allows read and write with the device using HID API. Hopw will help u know doing operation on device